# How do I find the position of a certain value given a second array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am comparing two arrays, and I need to figure out at which position the duplicates occur. I have to map the array, but am unsure on how to do that. In the end I want to have a filtered array. 1 indicates there is a duplicate, and "" indicates there is no duplicate.

```
var Strarr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
var importarr = ["1", "3"]

filteredArray = ["1", "", "1", ""]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let result = Strarr.map { importarr.contains($0) ? "1" : ""}

print(result) // ["1", "", "1", ""]
```

A bit shorter.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
var Strarr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
var importarr = ["1", "3"]

var newArray = Strarr
for i in 0..<Strarr.count {
    if importarr.contains(Strarr[i]) {
        newArray[i] = "1"
    }
    else{
        newArray[i] = "0"
    }
}
print(newArray)
```

prints `"["1", "0", "1", "0"]\n"`

Answer (score 0):

this should do it

```
var Strarr = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
var importarr = ["1", "3"]
var filteredArray = Strarr.map(function(val){
   return importarr.indexOf(val) != -1 ? "1" : "";
});
```